# How to set TTL to columns that are mentioned in where clause when using UPDATE

Tags: cassandra, cql

I understand that Cassandra updates the ttl to all the columns that I insert when I am `USING TTL`. But how can I update the ttl for rest of the columns that are mentioned in where clause.

Here is an example

```
   UPDATE NerdMovies (movie, director, main_actor, year)
   VALUES ('Serenity', 'Joss Whedon', 'Nathan Fillion', 2005) where
   language = 'English' and country = 'US'
   USING TTL 86400;
```

This only updates the columns `movie, director, main_actor, year`.I want to update the TTL for columns `language and country` too (which are primary keys by the way). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set TTL on primary keys. You can vote for a feature to do this at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9312 (but may not apply to your use case, if all columns are not PK).

You could read out the values and then upsert them with the TTL, like:

```
   INSERT INTO NerdMovies (movie, director, main_actor, year, language, country)
   VALUES ('Serenity', 'Joss Whedon', 'Nathan Fillion', '2005', 'English', 'US')
   USING TTL 86400;
```

Comment: How does this work with update? Lets say the same query using update

Comment: An update doesn't work, because you can't set TTL on primary keys: 

update NerdMovies using ttl 60
             ...    set movie='S3renlty', director='Joss Whedon', main_actor='Nathan Fillion', year='2005', language='English', country='US'
             ...    where language='English' and country='US';
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="PRIMARY KEY part language found in SET part"